# How to reload .bashrc settings without logging out and back in again?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, bashrc, bash-history

I created a script that add's the below commands to the .bashrc file. The purpose is I need to store the commands entered by the user into the .bash_history. The below commands are adding to .bashrc file when I ran the script file, but the .bashrc changes are not getting effected until I reload the .bashrc file by logging out from the session and logging in again.

Is there any command that can be included in my script file so that when the script file is executed it reload's or refresh the .bashrc file also.

Here is my **`script.sh`**

```
#!/bin/bash
    
for user_dir in /home/* /root; do
       user=$(basename "$user_dir")
       if [ -f "$user_dir/.bashrc" ]; then
          echo "$command_to_add" | tee -a "$user_dir/.bashrc" > /dev/null
          echo "$timestamp_command" | tee -a "$user_dir/.bashrc" > /dev/null
          echo "Added $command_to_add to $user's .bashrc"
       else
          echo "$user does not have a .bashrc file." | wall
       fi
    done
```

I tried including the command `source $user_dir/.bashrc` in the script file but it didn't worked.

Currently I am running the script using C# Process class so running the command `source script.sh` also didn't worked.

Comment: Your script (or any script) is run in a sub-shell ... i.e one that is different than the currently running shell where you wrote the command to execute the script ... Sourcing will affect that shell and when your script finishes executing and it's shell terminates, those affects are gone ... You could add e.g. `source $user_dir/.bashrc` to the end of your script file and source that script file (not execute) in the running shell.

Comment: ... Oh! ... You seem to run a script that will affect many user's `.bashrc` files at once ... In that case if what you mean is to "reload" `.bashrc` in all currently running shells for all users then that is not practically simply possible.

Comment: Yes, the script writes the mentioned commands to all the users .bashrc files, so i need to reload the .bashrc to effect those changes. Tried source $user_dir/.bashrc but it didn't worked

Comment: I’m afraid you can’t do that nowadays too many complications including but not limited to kernel's processes scopes and how shells work (there is no such global command for that by default nor it’s normally possible to instantaneously make one AFAIK) … Even the shell process that you start from the C program will terminate without affecting other users' shells or even its siblings in the same userspace and parent shells if any … In short, no native or even practical way of doing this is even logically possible … You can have users shells periodically source the rc file but it’s not practical.